# How to know the url/website a httpd process is serving?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I have several websites set up on a host. Using the "top" command, I see a lot of httpd processes that consume most of CPU. I want to know if I can get the url(or at least the website) each httpd process is serving so that I can do further investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [mod_status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html).

It generates a page which shows in (almost) real-time:

- The number of workers serving requests
- The number of idle workers
- The status of each worker, the number of requests that worker has performed and the total number of bytes served by the worker (*)
- A total number of accesses and byte count served (*)
- The time the server was started/restarted and the time it has been running for
- Averages giving the number of requests per second, the number of bytes served per second and the average number of bytes per request (*)
- The current percentage CPU used by each worker and in total by all workers combined (*)
- The current hosts and requests being processed (*)

Options (*) require `ExtendedStatus On`, which is the default nowadays.

It is also used by the `apachectl status` and `apachectl fullstatus` commands to show this information to the console.